# Is there any spiritual value in owning an item that once belong to a tzaddik?

Tags: tzaddikim, ownership

In seeing a discussion online regarding an item which ostensibly belong to a righteous person sold online for a [large sum of money](http://www.ebay.com/itm/332339177894) one of the comments stated that there was "an inyan to own the chafetz of a tzaddik" - ie some spiritual benefit in owning something which was once owned by a righteous person. I would like to know if there is a source for this idea and if so what the parameters might be

Comment: could it be possible that the comment made was to attract higher bids?